# Converting kernel density or heatmap into probability in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, density, kernel-density

I have a question regarding kernel density estimation in ArcMap, I want to know probability of use for my species in an area.

How do I change the final kernel density raster results into 50%, 75% and 95% probability of occurrence. ArcGIS used to have a KDE function that made it easier before, but since they discontinued it, I am not sure if it is in the software in any other way. I eventually need to find probability of occurrence of the species in the patches.

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. You have two questions here, and two platforms listed, which works out to four effective questions. Please [Edit] the Question to choose one platform, and your most pressing issue.

Comment: Done. Kindly please reopen the question.

Comment: You still have both ArcMap and QGIS in title, body, and tags.

Comment: Done. I do need help asap so I would appreciate if it is posted in the community. I was hoping someone will know one way or the other.